# Restore version 1 of a file and the original user

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, version-history, version, last-modified-date

I accidentally modified a file on SharePoint, thus showing my name on the 'Modified By' column and changing the modified date. Is there a way to return the file to its version 1 including the original user and modified date? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Select the file -> Click ellipses -> Select Version History -> Choose the version you want -> Restore
[image]

[image]
Reference:

[Restore a previous version of an item or file in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-a-previous-version-of-an-item-or-file-in-sharepoint-f66dbda0-81f4-4d1e-b08c-793265c58934)

Comment: But that will create a new version and will also reflect my name, not the original creator of the file, right?

Comment: It will create a new version. If you restore version 1, the modified date and modified users of version 1 will be restored. Update a picture in the answer.